# Freezing of a beverage

Tags: thermodynamics, aqueous-solution, water, colligative-properties

I am trying to generally describe the process of freezing beer and how the different ingredients influence the freezing process. My general approach right now is to observe a beer as 90% water and 10% beer substance, which would make a binary system, since the composition is way too complex to describe otherwise. In Germany there exists a beer specialty, that is called "Eisbock" and in basically a freeze concentration of a beer.
As stated above, I am trying to describe this process.
I have only little expertise in working on thermodynamic topics. So any help regarding this I appreciated.
 My general goal would be to bridge the gap from describing beer to water.
I have since found out that colligative properties play a role, the freeze kinetics and the heat/ mass transfer.
Also, I have been looking through the internet for a paper that describe to me how liquid/ solid phase transition works or is influenced. But the process has not been easy. That's why I am now trying to get some input via this forum.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: That 10% "beer substance" would be before fermentation, where most of approx 5% of formed CO2 would escape during the process.

Comment: That would be after fermentation. And my goal is first to take a broad look. Then the influence of certain substances

Comment: @Poutnik Besides ~4% of ethanol there's similar amount of sugars, proteins etc.

Comment: @Mithoron I have just meant that the usual marking of Czech beers - 10% or 12% is the most typical, means 10 or 12% of fermentable extract from the malt, giving at hypothetical (never that much) 100% fermentation around 5-6% of alcohol and about that much CO2. There is 0.3 - 0.5% of proteins.

Comment: Freezing soda, tea, cider, OJ, beer, usually results in pure ice coated with a concentrated liquid containing everything else until the eutectic is reached, if the container does not rupture. This was a common way to make applejack in very cold climates. Ferment some cider and place the barrel in the outside cold until it froze, then tap the center.

Comment: thanks for the info with the eutectic point @jimchmst